# “bigger question” vs. “larger question”

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, collocation

Would you say “a **bigger**” OR “a **larger** question”?

I am not sure which one is grammatically correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24499/50044

Comment: Usually they mean the same thing. But here, **bigger** means more important. So a *bigger question* is a question with more importance. **Larger** just means more size. So unless the question can be measured in units of length, it's incorrect to say *larger question.*

Comment: @NVZ - Google returns hundreds of instances of `the larger question is` in both [published books](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+larger+question&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22the+larger+question+is%22&safe=off&tbm=bks) and [contemporary news stories](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+larger+question&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22the+larger+question+is%22&safe=off&tbm=nws&start=110). I don't think it's "incorrect."

Comment: @J.R. Maybe it's just incorrect to my ears. I'm not a native English speaker. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You need to provide some context, what exactly do you want to say, gives us a full sentence? What makes you think that *large* might be better or worse  than *big*?

Comment: Neither of them are grammatically incorrect. The larger question would be: When might one be more appropriate than the other?

Comment: @J.R. An even bigger question: Is it better suited to ELL? Can you migrate it?

Comment: @NVZ - Perhaps this will be migrated eventually; I can't migrate it myself. However, it might be more useful to provide a link to [ell.se], so this new user will know what ELL means.

Comment: Whichever one turns you on.

Comment: Bigger is more for the significance, larger is more for dealing with the whole situation. For example:  "The bigger question is if you want to get the surgery, the larger question is will your insurance pay for the surgery and the related expenses.

Answer (score 1):

> *Large* is a bit more formal and stronger than *big*.
>   *Large* also emphasizes "big in more than one dimensions (like area or volume)".
>
> - *"We need a larger cup."* (Need more volume)
> - *"We need a bigger knife."* (No volume emphasized)
> - *"I wear large size clothing."*
> - *"This is a large backyard."* (big in length and width)
> - *"I've never seen such a big bear."* (No emphasis on the bear's volume or area)

Reference: http://www.grammarbank.com/big-large-great.html

As you cannot define an actual area or volume for the noun "Question" it's more likely to say big or bigger question.

However there is a book by J. Bronowski called "Large Questions", which means that the term "large question" or "Larger Question" isn't incorrect.