# Is it ok to say "a big set of nodes" or should i use the word "large"?

Tags: mathematics

It feels to me as if "big" in this context is focusing on the word "set" and not the number of things inside the set. For example, what if the nodes could be of different sizes and I want to focus on the number of them rather than the total size of them.

Do I just have a bias against the word "big" or is my intuition correct?

Comment: If you're not sure you like the word "big", why not play it safe and use "large".

Comment: Or, change to "number" instead of "set", which will remove any ambiguity.

Comment: I cannot change it to "number", because I have an actual set. With notation and all. :D  My thesis advisor is not a native speaker and he wrote "big set", but neither am I, so I don't want to change it unless I actually have a reason to.

Comment: Whether it is the *set* or the *nodes* that are big/large depends on word order. However, I would use "large" just because it sounds slightly more formal.

Comment: Can you give an example? A best answer here sounds like it will depend on context.

Comment: Actually the answer i was looking for is in the comment, not the answer itself. The question already is an example. The set is like a set in programming, it's already a specific object. And then i wanted to know how you might refer to the number of elements inside the object rather than the size of it itself. Like lets say you have some set S, which uses a small amount of memory but has many objects inside it. Then i thought saying "a big set S" might be unclear, but the answering person said that they would already think it's referring to the number of elements so I'm convinced.

Comment: "...a big set of nodes" sounds like something a really macho mathematician would have.

Comment: Cascabel: haha :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mathematician here! I highly suggest using "large" in this scenario.**

If I were reading a scholarly paper and a set was described as "big", I would bristle a little bit. There's nothing inherently wrong with it; rather, it would just "sound funny" to my ears, and I believe other mathematicians would say the same. If I read about "a large set", though, I wouldn't blink at all.

To wit, [the Wikipedia page for the word "Large"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large#Mathematics) even has a subcategory of phrases in mathematics that use that word (e.g. large cardinals, the law of large numbers, etc.). The page for "Big" has no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, as an English speaker, I would say "a big set of nodes" would mean a set of nodes with a large number of elements, while "a set of big nodes" would mean a set of nodes which were each individually large. However, I suspect that there might be field-specific jargon involved here - you may be better off asking in the Mathematics Stack Exchange, where mathematics specialists can answer your question.

That said, however, like some of the comments mentioned, "large" means roughly the same thing, and is slightly more formal than "big" is, so it may be more appropriate for an academic paper - however, it's possible that "large sets" is some sort of specifically-defined mathematical jargon that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Word order is not in question here. I'm asking whether it should be "a big set of nodes" or " a large set of nodes". So you are saying that both are correct to mean a large number of nodes in the set, but large is more formal?

Comment: @Mederr Yeah, but it's possible that there's field-specific jargon that I don't know, and which you'd need to ask a mathematician about.

Comment: I'm sure my advisor would know about anything like that. If "big" is ok, I'll just leave it like that. Thanks!